# Which of these is a better method of error handling?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, lambda, goto

Lets say you have multiple points in a function that could lead to the same failure. Which of these methods would be better? Is there an even better alternative?

```c++
{
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition0) goto fail;
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition1) goto fail;
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition2) goto fail;
    ...
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else goto fail;
    ...
    return;

fail:
    /* handle error here */
    ...
}
```

or

```c++
{
    auto fail = [] {
        /* handle error here */
        ... 
    };
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition0) fail();
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition1) fail();
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition2) fail();
    ...
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else fail();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not `if (some_failure_conditionX) throw some_exception;`?

Comment: @praetorian To avoid unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: Use exception to control the flow is the wrong way of using exception!! And if code is dup, just write a free function.

Comment: You're repeating the same, short expression. I wouldn't worry too much about duplication in this case. Another option might be `auto throw_if_fail = [](bool failed) { if(failed) throw some_exception; }; throw_if_fail(some_failure_conditionX);`

Comment: And your question is more like " what is a better way of throwing exception"

Comment: @billz I don't follow you. some_failure_conditionX are something that is not expected to be encountered normally, and if it is, then the function has no option but to fail. That sounds exceptional to me.

Comment: @Praetorian For the sake of argument you can assume that the error handling code may actually do more than simply throw an exception. This was only intended to be a short brief example.

Comment: Given the latest update, I don't really have a preference between the two. If the lambda works, then choose that as it'll appease the `goto` Nazis. But in such cases, my opinion is that using a `goto` is perfectly valid too.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is C++ and not C, the better alternative is to use exceptions which helps to guarantee that destructors are called appropriately:

```
try
{
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition0) throw fail;
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition1) throw fail;
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition2) throw fail;
    ...
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else throw fail;
    ...
    return;
}
catch(const fail& f)
    /* handle error here */
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it all depends what the semantics of your function is. I would usually avoid goto (I have not used it in years), and also avoid C-style error handling with return codes. For error handling, I stick to the following guidelines:

1. Use RAII for resources to get automatic exception-safe handling, e.g. no explicit calls to new.
2. When a function fails to establish its postcondition (and the class invariant, if it is a member function), throw an exception. I would e.g. throw a network connection you want to receive data from is not opened, but not if receiving data over the network fails because there is no data available.
3. If the "error" is an expected result of the function, e.g. receiving data over the network but nobody has sent data, I would use a return-type which can handle that. In the example, it could be an empty vector, but in general something like boost::optional makes sense.
4. Code that needs to be executed when a function is done should be in scope-guards. Most often this a temporary RAII object, so I often create a new RAII to re-use it.

This has made code like your example obsolete most of the time in my life.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
#define MY_FAIL_CHECK(_condition) if(_condition) { throw some_exception; }

void foo()
{
  MY_FAIL_CHECK(some_failure_condition0);
  MY_FAIL_CHECK(some_failure_condition1);
  MY_FAIL_CHECK(some_failure_condition2);
}
```

Comment: Why? What's better about this? Now I've got a preprocessor macro.

Comment: 1. No duplicate code 
2. Inline assembly code, without calling functions 
3. Code easier to read (without `goto`)

Comment: Well goto is easier to read as it's specified in language standard. Whereas you must get acquainted with cusom macro.

Comment: @Sheridan Besides, you interpreted my example as being very specific when I intended it to be more general. I've updated it.

Comment: Clear. I would use a macro or lambda. But better way of error handling is exceptions

Comment: @PovilasB If the macro is declared just before the code (for the particular case), it is easier with macros.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, there is no sound reason to use goto in place of exceptions.

Comment: If you are using c++, there is no reason to avoid goto if the sense is clear, simple and straight forward. Using an exception instead of goto is also bad practice if the program flow is not really exceptional!

Answer (score 0):

I would create sub function(s), something like:

```
bool foo() // or enum or boost::optional
{
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition0) return false;
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition1) return false;
    ...
    if (some_failure_condition2) return false;
    ...
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else return false;
    ...
    return true;
}

void bar()
{
    auto result = foo();
    if (!result)
    {
        /* handle error here */
        ...
    }
}
```

Don't forget to use RAII to avoid some handling which may be automatic.